# My arraylist is only outputting the last value

Tags: java, string

I created a HashMap to store a text file with the columns of information. I compared the key to a specific name and stored the values of the HashMap into an ArrayList. When I try to `println` my ArrayList, it only outputs the last value and leaves out all the other values that match that key.

This isn't my entire code just my two loops that read in the text file, stores into the HashMap and then into the ArrayList. I know it has something to do with my loops.

Did some editing and got it to output, but all my values are displayed multiple times.

My output looks like this.
North America:
[ Anguilla,  Anguilla,  Antigua and Barbuda,  Antigua and Barbuda,  Antigua and Barbuda,  Aruba,  Aruba,  Aruba,

```
HashMap<String, String> both = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ArrayList<String> sort = new ArrayList<String>();
    //ArrayList<String> sort2 = new ArrayList<String>();



    // We need a try catch block so we can handle any potential IO errors
    try {
    try {
        inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        String lineContent = null;
    // Loop will iterate over each line within the file.
    // It will stop when no new lines are found.
    while ((lineContent = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
        String column[]= lineContent.split(","); 
        both.put(column[0], column[1]);


        Set set = both.entrySet(); 
        //Get an iterator 
        Iterator i = set.iterator(); 
        // Display elements 

        while(i.hasNext()) { 
        Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();

        if(me.getKey().equals("North America"))
        {   
            String value= (String) me.getValue();
            sort.add(value);

        }

    }


    }
    System.out.println("North America:");
    System.out.println(sort);
    System.out.println("\n");


    }
```

Comment: Could you show the declarations for `sort` (not an ideal name for a variable, by the way) -- I'm guessing it is the arraylist to which you refer? Also, you could try printing the length of `sort` to ensure that there is, in fact, more than one item in the arraylist.

Answer (score 2):

Map keys need to be unique. Your code is working according to spec.

Comment: Just to elaborate, any time you put a new value in for a key, it overwrites the old value associated with that key.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to have many values for a key, you may use

```
 Map<key,List<T>>
```

here T is String (not only list you can use any collection)

Answer (score 0):

Some things seems wrong with your code :

- you are iterating on the `Map` `EntrySet` to get just one value (you could just use the following code :

  ```
  if (both.containsKey("North America"))
      sort.add(both.get("North America"));
  ```
- it seems that you can have "North America" more than one time in your input file, but you are storing it in a `Map`, so each time you store a new value for "North America" in your `Map`, it will overwrite the current value
- I don't know what the type of `sort` is, but what is printed by `System.out.print(sort);` is dependent of the `toString()` implementation of this type, and the fact that you use `print()` instead of `println()` may also create problems depending on how you run your program (some shells may not print the last value for instance).

If you want more help, you may want to provide us with the following things :

- sample of the input file
- declaration of `sort`
- sample of output
- what you want to obtain.